# How to add inline mode in telegram bot

Tags: java, telegram, telegram-bot

I try to create the telegram bot in Java, and I need to add inline buttons in there. I looked at the official documentation [official documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#answercallbackquery) and everything I made - the button, but they don't work. I also check all GitHub Java examples, but it didn't help. I don't understand how I can obtain the answer of pressing to this button and do something with. For example, If the user presses this button - send him something.
Here is my code:

```
public void sending(Long chatID, File photo) {
    InlineKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new InlineKeyboardMarkup();
    InlineKeyboardButton button = new InlineKeyboardButton();

    List<List<InlineKeyboardButton>> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    List<InlineKeyboardButton> buttonList = new ArrayList<>();
    button.setText("Just button");
    button.setCallbackData("callBack");
    buttonList.add(button);
    buttons.add(buttonList);
    keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(buttons);

    SendPhoto sending = new SendPhoto();
    sending.setChatId(chatID.toString());
    sending.setNewPhoto(photo);
    sending.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);
    try {
        sendPhoto(sending);
    } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Now I have only this error 
`PM org.telegram.telegrambots.logging.BotLogger severe
SEVERE: BOTSESSION
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at mybot.SimpleBot.onUpdateReceived(SimpleBot.java:62)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.BotSession$HandlerThread.run(BotSession.java:197)`

I would be really appreciated if somebody gives me some tips or simple java code with using callback buttons.

Comment: @kayaman How is this question a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it ?

Comment: @CharlesOkwuagwu He edited out the "Now I have only this error `<NPE stacktrace>`" part.

Comment: Rolled this back to the original version because otherwise it doesn't make sense why it was closed as a duplicate. Also, the original version has the most information about what was going wrong.

Comment: I was also surprised how that post is similar. Thanks for rolled back!

Comment: By the way, I received the callback data, it needs to do in another override method -  `public void onUpdateReceived(Update update)`. Just check the press off button `callbackQuery = update.getCallbackQuery();     if (callbackQuery.getData().equals("callBack")){//do thomething}`. Now I have another question - how I can use the EditMessageText - if the button were pressed it would disappear? Any suggestion?

Comment: If it would be helpful for somebody this is the answer to my last question: `editMessageReplyMarkup.setChatId(callbackQuery.getMessage().getChatId().toString())
                        .setMessageId(callbackQuery.getMessage().getMessageId()).setReplyMarkup(new InlineKeyboardMarkup());
                try {
                    editMessageReplyMarkup(editMessageReplyMarkup);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }`

Comment: @HerbertVincent You can edit your question instead of trying to put the code in the comments. As you see it isn't very readable.

Comment: Sorry for this, I'm new at StackOverflow.